# OneLogin SAML logout functionality

Tags: saml, onelogin, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I want to implement logout functionality for Onelogin SAML in ASP.net MVC. 
Can anyone please share me sample application for Onelogin SAML logout functionality with redirection.

I have already refer onelogin site.
https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/examples/logout-response

still not getting response.

Answer (score 2):

The Onelogin dot-net SAML toolkit is a proof of concept as described in [its repository](https://github.com/onelogin/dotnet-saml).

You should use another SAML toolkit (alternatives listed on the repo).

btw, check this [SingleLogout class](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/553ed3f28d80d19f857a54d0f5ac382f4789ab30/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2LogoutRequest.cs) used on that [view](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/553ed3f28d80d19f857a54d0f5ac382f4789ab30/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L81) that executes a single logout request (extracted from the SAML toolkit of ITfoxtec).